# How to add a content query web part into Page layout?

Tags: page-layout, content-query-web-part

In each site there is a list called "Feedback". I want to create a custom page layout that will query the "Feedback" for certain condition (e.g. latest 5 rows that URL=xxx) and list at the bottom of page according to a custom display tempalte.

May I know how should I start? Any reference is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SharePoint Designer you can edit a page layout and create a CQWP. If you need to customise the CQWP, you probably need to export it, edit it, and import it again. But unlike the SharePoint browser interface, SPD does not have a command to import a web part.

You can do this:

Create the CQWP on a web part page. Export it, modify it as desired, then import it back into the web part page via the browser.

Open the web part page with SPD, and also open the page layout. Create a new CQWP in the page layout, then swap out the code of that new CQWP with the code from the CQWP on the web part page. The new CQWP needs to keep a few crucial settings in the opening control tag; all other parameters in the control tag can be copied from the imported CQWP.

I've written the whole procedure up in an [article here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/8490/SharePoint-Designer-2010-Upload-a-Web-Part.html) a few years ago.